# How to add special characters/spaces in classes(Named Individuals) of Ontology

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

Is it possible to add spaces/characters in Named Individuals of ontology? if yes, How? if No, why this limitation? I am using Fluent editor for creating model. Previously protege was used where I got many blank nodes. so I moved to Fluent editor. Here I am encountered this problem

Comment: Why should Fluent editor be different? And I still don't know why you're scared about blank nodes...those are usually "hidden" in Protege and are just necessary for the RDF serialization of OWL.

Comment: Spaces in Named Individuals? Well, that would be the same as asking for spaces in URIs/IRIs which in fact is how a named individual is represented in OWL.

Comment: Hi,first I have tried with protege but got blank nodes where graphical representation is very good but, I found no relation to make queries on it. I was unable to find the reason for that so I moved to Fluent editor where the triples formed are as expected to query but the diagram is not. Here, I have spaces and special characters in my content/data. I am in dilemma to overcome the problem to use case sensitive,special characters and spaces in NamedIndividuals

Comment: Well I still don't get what you mean by issues with blank nodes. Protege is an OWL editor, in fact you'll only see OWL constructs in the editor. Blank nodes are part of the RDF data model, indeed, you'll see them in the RDF serialization of OWL, but not in Protege. Things like "diagrams" and "querying" are different things, clearly in SPARQL you have to work on the RDF layer. Diagrams, not sure what you mean by this...

Comment: Regarding spaces, best practice is to provide human-readable forms as a property attached to the resource (resp. individual) - URIs are not made for humans in general although nice to have but easy to workaround. Look at Wikidata, it just uses IDs like [wd:Q27745011](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q27745011) - and it works nevertheless, people are happy with it and able to work on the data.

Comment: Special characters in IRIs are a definite no. Use labels or comments and make sure to convert the characters to the right encoding - usually UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Named individuals use IRIs for identification, and these cannot contain spaces. Spaces in IRIs need to be percent-encoded, so they get translated to  the string %20.

In order to use human readable names, create rdf:label values for your individuals. The content is then free text.